# how to skip dialog based on selected feature

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, msi-gui

I want to add a custom dialog in the UI sequence after the Feature
selection (Customize) dialog. The feature selection is done through a
Feature tree. How can I figure out if a particular feature was
selected and launch the custom dialog?

Right now I am having the following codes
In this case, it displays the VirtualDirectoryDlg and then the SqlDatabaseDlg.  I want it to display SqlDatabaseDlg only if the feature was selected and if it`s disabled it should not be displayed.

Can I have some examples or tutorials as I am completely new to it.  Thanks

```
  <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VirtualDirectoryDlg" Order="1"><![CDATA[&WebApplicationFeature = 3]]></Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="SqlDatabaseDlg" Order="2"><![CDATA[&WebApplicationFeature <> 3]]></Publish>
```

I have seen the following but can`t figure out how to use them with my codes

> Feature table key &   Action state of the feature. Feature table
>   key   !   Installed state of the feature.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368561(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, MSI has a limitation that a feature state won't record until after you changed to another dialog.  You are doing it right, it just won't work.  I would transition to another dialog (SqlDatabaseDlg probably) and then on the next button of that dialog do your checks and transition to VirtualDirectoryDlg or whatever dialog would come next if WebApplicationFeature isn't being installed.